# subtract line's in CSV

Tags: csv

..I need to modify several CSV's as follow's...

This is what I have:

```
2012-08-13 00:15:15; 768.548
2012-08-13 00:30:15; 768.625
2012-08-13 00:45:15; 768.667
2012-08-13 01:00:15; 768.729
2012-08-13 01:15:15; 768.785
2012-08-13 01:30:15; 768.827
```

But what I need for my analyses is this:

```
2012-08-13 00:15:15; xxx
2012-08-13 00:30:15; 0.077
2012-08-13 00:45:15; 0.042
2012-08-13 01:00:15; 0.062
2012-08-13 01:15:15; 0.056
2012-08-13 01:30:15; 0.042
```

What I need to do is subtract the actual line from the line above.

I've done some simple shell script's which calculate the sum of those file's but never did something that complex...

And there's an extra challenge: the first line/value need's to be subtracted by the value from the day before which is in another CSV.

Hope you can help

Comment: That's not really a CSV, is it ? Is it semi-colon-separated ?

Comment: It is a real CSV... There was a mistake in the what I need example, seperator is not the comma it's the dot!

Comment: Reading it the third time I got your question right... Yes it's semi-colon seperated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a little awk script?

```
awk -F';' 'NR==1 {print $1 "; xxx"}; NR > 1 {print $1 "; " $2 - x} {x=$2}' < your_file.csv
```

As for the first line (where it's `xxx` at the moment), I'd write a little shell function:

```
get_last_value()
{
## first argument is the filename
    tail -n 1 $1 | cut -d';' -f2
}
```

and then modify the snippet above to

```
awk -F';' 'NR==1 {print $1 "; " $2 - '$(get_last_value PREVIOUS)'}; NR > 1 {print $1 "; " $2 - x} {x=$2}' THIS_FILE
```

and then all you need to do is obtain the combinations of `PREVIOUS` and `THIS_FILE` for each call.  Also note that the very first file must be processed with the untweaked snippet above (as there is no previous value).

Comment: First work's like expected, thx so far! The 2nd special part sadly doesn't. I'm stuck with THIS_FILE, even if I change it to: 'awk -F';' 'NR==1 {print $1 "; " $2 - '$(get_last_value $2)'}; NR > 1 {print $1 "; " $2 - x} {x=$2}' < $1'

Comment: does `get_last_value` work on its own?  if so, then it must be a substitution problem in the shell, is there any error messages?